# Issue with permissions on PHP, even chmod isnt working

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

i am having a little problem here, i am trying to upload an image but i am receiving `Permission Denied` error.

So i added a `chmod 0777` to targeted directory, but i can not use chmod either, its giving me `Permission Denied` too for it

Anything i can do ?

Comment: Seems like a problem in your php environment. Try to edit and describe where and how you are hosting your php files.

Comment: What OS is the server running? Do you know how security is set up on the server? (e.g. does each website or PHP-CGI process run under its own user identity/security context?)

Comment: need more information on your environment

Comment: If you are using SELinux like CentOS or Fedora, try searching for SELinux policies. More specifically, the `chcon` command is what you need.

Comment: where you root when you tried to change the permission?

Answer (score 0):

The *chmod* command allows you to control who is allowed to have access to your files and directories which means that in case you are not the owner of a certain file/directory or in case you are not having sufficient permissions to change permissions for a file/directory then you are going to get `Permission Denied` error or something similar.

To avoid you can run *chmod* as `sudo chmod 775 directoryName;`